# Responsive Email Template Problems on a Mobile Device

Tags: responsive-design, html-email, email-templates

I have a responsive template that works perfectly and it is excellent in a PC whenever i re-size it at any width. But it is not responsive when i look at Gmail in my Andriod Mobile Phone. My Email Template has all the appropriate media queries and widths set to 100%.

I can't figure out a solution. It will be very helpful if someone gave a permanent solution.

If anyone want to see the file and give out a solution here it is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkvdw5cg50...late.html?dl=0

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Gmail on Android, Gmail on iOS, and Gmail on the web do not support media queries.  You can settle for graceful degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail on Android does not support media query.

Comment: Do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: Nope, it's simply not supported at the moment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: make sure your biggest table has `style="min-width:[width]px"` so gmail doesn't resize everything